# install keyword significance in yocto recipe

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to understand recipes in Yocto and I have seen this keyword 'install' used everywhere. Project Reference Manual do not say anything about this keyword

what is the significance of 'install' keyword in yocto recipes.. what is the benefit of using it in compare to touch for creating file and mkdir

```
do_install () {
         autotools_do_install
         install -d ${D}${base_bindir}
         mv ${D}${bindir}/sed ${D}${base_bindir}/sed
         rmdir ${D}${bindir}/
     }
```

Comment: it allows you to control the attributes of destination files.

Comment: can you give an example to understand

Comment: random picked: `install -d -m 710 ${D}/${localstatedir}/lib/openvpn` creates `openvpn` folder with `chmod 710`. It also creates parent dirs, see [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html)

Comment: I thinks there is provided good answer for Your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/95932